# not able to attach a file (csv file) in input field using Behat Mink extension Framework

Tags: php, javascript, behat, mink

I want to attach a CSV file in to an input field of type "file" using Behat Framework(Mink Extension).

Html of input field---- input id="edit-ab-csv-file" class="form-file" type="file" size="60" name="files[ab_csv_file]">

1st Method We tried 
I have tried using attachfile() method in Driverinterface

```
/**
 * Attaches file to field with specified id|name|label|value.
 *
 * @When /^(?:|I )attach the file "(?P<path>[^"]*)" to "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
 */

 public function attachFileToField($field, $path)
{
    $field = $this->fixStepArgument($field);

    if ($this->getMinkParameter('files_path')) {
        $fullPath = rtrim(realpath($this->getMinkParameter('files_path')), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path;
        if (is_file($fullPath)) {
            $path = $fullPath;
        }
    }

    $this->getSession()->getPage()->attachFileToField($field, $path);
}


}
```

2nd Method --WE tried to use Java script

```
$jscript = "document.getElementById('edit-ab-csv-file').value='//home//developer//build//tools//behat//Invaliduploadfile.csv';";
  $this->getSession()->getDriver()->executeScript($jscript);
```

I got an exception saying

```
 The operation is insecure. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stack trace information)
      Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
```

can anyone please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First method is working for me. Don't forget to use the complete path to the file or use files_path Mink config setting.

Check this forum post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/behat/vxZAssi2Nf8

> Mink requires an absolute path to upload a file, but obviously that
>   path probably won't work in other environments. Instead, you can
>   provide a "file_paths" property to your Yaml configuration file:
>
> extensions:
>
> ```
> Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
>
>     files_path: "path/to/files"
> ```

Comment: In Behat 3 you can use `%paths.base%` to make your directory relative to where you're running your tests from. Eg: `files_path: %paths.base%/app/Test/Behat/Files`

Comment: In Behat 2 you can use `%behat.paths.base%` for what Daniel suggested.